# como puedo capturar en un array el texto de una linea de un archivo txt ? en la shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

quiero capturar el texto de cada linea de un archivo de texto 
texto ejemplo

Por último, os indico que si invocamos el comando sin opciones de conteo (contar las líneas, las palabras, etc), el comando nos devolverá directamente cuatro columnas: la cuenta de palabras, de líneas y de bytes totales del archivo.

quisiera capturar cada linea en un array o una variable  en bash

Comment: no queda claro qué pretendes, Yeko. ¿Podrías dar un [mcve]¿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo así.

```
$ declare -a array_lineas
$ i=0
$ while read linea
> do
> array_lineas[$i]="$linea"
> ((i++))
> done <<< "$(echo -e 'linea1\nlinea2\nlinea3')"
$ echo "${array_lineas[@]}"
linea1 linea2 linea3
```

Ahí usé un here-string, pero con un archivo debería ser algo así.

```
$ declare -a array_lineas  # declaro array_lineas como una variable de tipo array
$ i=0  # inicializo el contador
$ while read linea  # read puede leer línea por línea, i.e., según el delimitador de salto de línea
do
array_lineas[$i]="$linea"
((i++))
done < archivo.txt  # El bucle while se alimenta (su standard input) de archivo.txt
$ echo "${array_lineas[@]}"
linea1 linea2 linea3
```